# SQL query for finding representative rows in a table

Tags: sql, groupwise-maximum

Let's say I have a payments table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Payments (
  PaymentID INT,
  CustomerID INT,
  Value INT,
  PaidOn DATE
);

INSERT INTO Payments
  VALUES
(1, 1, 5, '2000-01-01'),
(2, 1, 10, '2000-02-01'),
(3, 2, 10, '2000-01-02'),
(4, 2, 10, '2000-01-20'),
(5, 2, 5, '2000-02-02'),
```

And I want to run a query for the entire row for the maximum payment made by each customer.  Is this possible using a single SQL query, to avoid having to dig through every row that I'm not interested -- or worse, run a query for each customer?

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Value)
  FROM Payments
  GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

But this does not give me the `PaymentId` or `PaidOn` values for the rows it finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will accomplish that. It pulls out all the rows for which there is not a greater Value.

```
SELECT *
FROM payments p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM payments p2
    WHERE p2.CustomerID = p.CustomerId
    AND   p2.Value > p.Value
)
```

Comment: This will probably not perform as well as Tony Andrew's, because the subquery has to be run for each customer.

Answer (score 10):

```
select PaymentID, CustomerID, Value, PaidOn
from payments
where (customerID, value) in
( select customerID, max(value)
  from payments 
  group by customerID
);
```

Note that this can return more than one row per customer if they have more than one payment with the maximum value.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much an identical question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374846/how-do-i-select-only-the-latest-entry-in-a-table) from earlier today.

To avoid subqueries you can also use:

```
SELECT
     P1.PaymentID,
     P1.CustomerID,
     P1.Value,
     P1.PaidOn
FROM
     Payments P1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments P2 ON
     P2.CustomerID = P1.CustomerID AND
     P2.Value > P1.Value
WHERE
     P2.PaymentID IS NULL
```

Depending on your business rules for ties on the value you will need to alter this query.

For example, to use the latest payment if there is a tie:

```
SELECT
     P1.PaymentID,
     P1.CustomerID,
     P1.Value,
     P1.PaidOn
FROM
     Payments P1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments P2 ON
     P2.CustomerID = P1.CustomerID AND
     (P2.Value > P1.Value OR (P2.Value = P1.Value AND P2.PaidOn > P1.PaidOn))
WHERE
     P2.PaymentID IS NULL
```

Comment: A moot point now, but it's not an identical question, even though the answers are quite similar. In the one earlier today, there is not a requirement for the record to be for the maximum amount.

Answer (score 0):

One more using Self join - matter of syntactic sugar. Easier to understand and good on performance.

```
select PaymentID, CustomerID, Value, PaidOn
from
( select customerID, max(value) as maxValue
  from payments 
  group by customerID
)as T
 INNER JOIN payments as P
  ON P.Value=T.maxValue AND P.CustomerID = T.CustomerID
```

-Maulik Modi

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, which uses a derived table:

```
SELECT     p2.PaymentId, p2.CustomerID, p2.Value, p2.PaidOn
FROM         Payments AS p2 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     CustomerID, MAX(Value) AS Value
     FROM          Payments
     GROUP BY CustomerID)
AS p1
ON p1.CustomerID = p2.CustomerID AND p1.Value = p2.Value
```